# OAuth Token Management for Same User, who logs in two different browsers - WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

In my web application, I use SAML2 bearer assertion profile to obtain OAuth tokens from WSO2 API Manager. I was get caught in to a problem when same user sign-in to web application in two different sessions.

At the first time they login, API Manger gives two unique OAuth tokens to these two session belong to same user. I think that's because SAML assertions are different even the user is same.

The problem rises up when the token get expired. The first session who refresh the token will get a new one. But when the second session tries to refresh it's token it gives exceptions.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://host:port/oauth2/token
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog explains the flow http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-configure-wso2-api-manager-to.html Currently if one session refreshes the token, other session have to get a new token.